# Can't display icon on dialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have WPF dialog and I want to add icon on it. In resource editor icon is visible but when I am runing application and open this dialog, there is no icon.

```
   <Image Source="/Resources/myimg.ico" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="10,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.714,0.6"/>
```

Build action of icon is content.

Comment: Is the icon file present at the location of the executable in a subdirectory named 'Resources'?  You might be better compiling the icon as an embedded resource and including it that way.

Comment: Is the icon correctly embedded into the application binaries or copied to the output path? (Properties -> Build Action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 'Build Action' is 'Content', the ico file will not be compiled into dll file, it will appears at output directory standalone.

So you should check the '**Copy to Output Directory**', it should be '**Copy always**' or '**Copy if newer**'.